# Intermittent ethernet connectivity

Tags: networking, indicator

I am facing a weird problem. I am connecting to my dsl modem via ethernet.

After booting, sometimes Ubuntu 10.10 does not detect the eth0 card properly or does not connect to the modem.

I have made the following observations:

1. My modem is fully on. All indicators are on except ethernet, which is blinking continuously.
2. My network indicator applet informs me that I am connected to modem, but I am not able to browse as it has not established connection with modem.
3. I need to power off and on (restart) the modem several times OR disconnect/connect (via network applet) several times, before the system can establish a connection with the modem.
4. Once it establishes the connection, the ethernet LED (on modem) stops blinking and glows continuously.

However, I do not see this problem every time I reboot or start my computer. 3/5 time, it connects to the modem in a single attempt.

Friends, I am not able to understand root cause of this problem. Plus I do not know what kind of logs should be attached. If you want any logs please give me command to run, and I will paste the result for you.

Note: I ran system testing when above problem happened. Follow this link to [download result](https://sites.google.com/site/ameyjah/result.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

Comment: Please, post the output of "ifconfig" command both when Internet works and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using e1000 module so you're using the latest driver.

Maybe you're hit by a weird issue i face from time to time: if I plug a gigabit network card on a 10 Mb ethernet port (hub, modem...), the card connects/disconnects all the time.

Do you have a 10/100 switch around there? A good try could be connect your computer to the switch and your dsl model to the switch, and see if you have that problem. Of course, get another cable to try it too ;-)